# Select from one table and depending on value in that table select from one or two other tables

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm doing some work on an old site that brings back lists of items.

At the moment, it does a query selecting the list items from one table, then loops through that query - and depending on a value in the first table - does a query on a second table, or a query on third and fourth table. So a list of 100 items could result in 101 queries being run!

This is the basic table layout;

```
**tblLists** ListID, ListType, ListTitle, tblPages_PageID, tblFiles_FileID, LinkAddress, Description

**tblPages** PageID, PageTitle, PagePath

**tblFiles** FileID, FileName, tblFileTypes_FileTypesID

**tblFileTypes** FileTypeID, FileTypeDescription, FileTypeIcon
```

tblLists.ListType can be one of 4 types. It can be;

1) 'Page' in which case tblLists.tblPages_PageID relates to PageID in the tblPages table. If its 'Page' it runs a query within the loop which selects PageTitle, PagePath from tblPages where tblPages.PageID = #tblPages_PageID#

2) 'File' in which case tblLists.tblFiles_FileID relates to FileID in the tblFiles table. If its 'File' it runs a query within the loop which selects tblFiles.FileName, tblFileTypes.FileTypeDescription , tblFileType.tblFileTypeIcon FROM tblFiles , tblFileTypes WHERE tblFiles.FileID = #tblFiles_FileID# and tblFiles.tblFileTypes_FileTypesID = tblFileTypes.FileTypeID

3) 'Link' in which case 'LinkAddress' will have a value. No further query is required.

4) 'Text' in which case 'Description' will have a value. No further query is required.

What i'd like to be able to do if possible is amalgamate the main query and all the then subsequent queries into one query.

So something like ( the sql is obviously not correct for the if statements - but thats kinda what i want to achieve! ),

```
select tblLists.ListType , tblLists.ListTitle , tblPages.PageTitle 
, tblPages.PagePath , tblFiles.FileName,tblFileTypes.FileTypeDescription 
, tblFileTypes.FileTypeIcon 

FROM tblLists , tblPages , tblFiles , tblFileTypes
WHERE ...

if type = 'page' 
select PageTitle, PagePath 
from tblPages 
where tblPages.PageID = tblLists.tblPages_PageID

or if type = 'file' 
select tblFiles.FileName, tblFileTypes.FileTypeDescription
, tblFileType.tblFileTypeIcon 
FROM tblFiles 
, tblFileTypes 
WHERE tblFiles.FileID = tblLists.tblFiles_FileID 
and tblFiles.tblFileTypes_FileTypesID = tblFileTypes.FileTypeID

or if type = 'link' no other work needed

or if type = 'text' no other work needed
```

Is this possible?!

Then i could run and output one query, for each record if the type was 'File' i'll have the required info from the tblFiles and tblFileTypes tables, if the type was 'Page' i'll have what i need from the tblPages table, and if its 'Link' or 'Text' i've got those two too.

Thanks for any help :)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Dan for nudging my brain, i've got this far;

```
SELECT tblLists.ListType , tblLists.ListTitle , tblLists.LinkAddress , tblLists.Description , tblFiles.FileName , tblPages.PageTitle , tblPages.PagePath

FROM tblLists

LEFT JOIN tblFiles ON tblLists.tblFiles_FileID = tblFiles.FileID
LEFT JOIN tblPages ON tblLists.tblPages_PageID = tblPages.PageID

WHERE tblLists.ListType = 'File'
AND tblLists.tblFiles_FileID = tblFiles.FileID

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Page'
AND tblLists.tblPages_PageID = tblPages.PageID

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Link'

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Text'

ORDER BY tblLists.ListTitle
```

all i need now is getting the tblFileTypes.ReferenceID = tblFiles.FileTypes_ReferenceID into the query - do i need like a left join on the left join?! ...

Comment: Seems you can add subqueries into SQL's CASE-WHEN-THEN statements. Should do what you are after. Check the following article, which explores how to return queries from CASE-WHEN-THEN statements:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx

Comment: Look into using a left join. That should get you what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.  This sort of structure should help you.  You'll have to sort out the details.

```
select yourFields 
from table1  t1 join table2 t2 on t1.something = t2.something
where someConditionsAreMet
and 
(
(someMoreConditionsAreMet)
or
(someOtherConditionsAreMet)
or 
(yetAnotherSetOfConditionsAreMet)
)
```

In your select clause, the coalesce function might help you with any conditional logic you need.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that was a great help - as soon as i saw the and/or i thought of course! I'm just stuck on one bit now i think, and thats getting the tblFileTypes.ReferenceID = tblFiles.FileTypes_ReferenceID into the query - i think i might need something like a left join on the left join?! ... 

I'll update my question to reflect where i'm currently at ... Thanks again Dan :)

Answer (score 0):

So, i was being a bit stupid ... this seems to be working, as simple as that!

```
SELECT tblLists.ListType , tblLists.ListTitle , tblLists.LinkAddress , tblLists.Description , tblFiles.FileName , tblPages.PageTitle , tblPages.PagePath , tblFileTypes.FileTypeDescription , tblFileTypes.FileTypeIcon 

FROM tblLists

LEFT JOIN tblFiles ON tblLists.tblFiles_FileID = tblFiles.FileID 
LEFT JOIN tblFileTypes ON tblFiles.tblFileTypes_FileTypeID = tblFileTypes.FileTypeID
LEFT JOIN tblPages ON tblLists.tblPages_PageID = tblPages.PageID

WHERE tblLists.ListType = 'File'
AND tblLists.tblFiles_FileID = tblFiles.FileID
AND tblFiles.tblFileTypes_FileTypeID = tblFileTypes.FileTypeID

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Page' 
AND tblLists.tblPages_PageID = tblPages.PageID

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Link'

OR tblLists.ListType = 'Text'

ORDER BY tblLists.ListTitle
```

Thanks again Dan, it was just seeing the WHERE/AND/OR that triggered it for me! I'd got into my head it was going to be really complex! :)

Comment: Make sure to add parentheses so that your AND/OR statements are unambiguous

Comment: Thanks Steve. Do you mean unambiguous to someone reading the code, or to MYSQL itself? I've never actually used parentheses in and/or statements - should i be?! The above without parentheses seems to be working.

Comment: Actually, you can replace the entire where clause with `where tblLists.ListType in ('File', 'Page', 'Link', 'Text')`.  The parts where fields are equal are redundant.  That was covered in the join statements.

Comment: Both. Mostly for humans. I can't tell just by looking at that code whether you want anything with a ListType of "Link" to show up regardless of whether the PageID or LinkID matches or not. I would have to experiment to see how MySQL would evaluate that. Adding parenthesis appropriately will ensure others can read your code and that MySQL interprets your AND/OR statements the way you intend.

Comment: Thanks @SteveBryant, i will look into parentheses. As it is, it works, but if i can make things clearer to me ( or whoever else ) and mysql then thats all good :)

Comment: @Luke - If you stumbled on an order that works "as is", it was mostly just luck ;-) Parenthesis are the only way to guarantee the [order of evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html) that will yield the specific results you want.  So do not think of them as optional. Whenever you mix AND/OR - *always* use parenthesis. Also, in case you missed [Dan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794617/select-from-one-table-and-depending-on-value-in-that-table-select-from-one-or-tw#comment45894174_28797010) a lot of that is redundant. It can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks @Leigh, i'll remember that - and check my existing code! And yeah, i saw Dan's comment, i've changed my query now to remove the unnecessary stuff, which makes the whole thing a lot easier to read and understand.

Comment: Sounds good. When you get a chance, update your answer with the streamlined code, so it clearer for the next guy :)